# Test Coverage for delete method

Tags: apex, code-coverage

I'm tying to get code coverage up to be able to commit my changes to prod org.
I have a method to delete a record based on a given ID, how can I make it throw an error and run through the catch block?

```
@AuraEnabled 
public static void deleteSelectedTimelog(String recordIdToDelete){
    try {
        delete [SELECT Id
        FROM Time_Log__c
        WHERE Id =: recordIdToDelete];
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new AuraHandledException(e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

test class

```
@isTest
static void testDeleteSelectedTimelogError(){
    Profile p = [SELECT Id FROM Profile WHERE Name = 'Standard User'];

    User u = new User(
        Username = 'test@user.com.performaittest',
        Lastname = 'last name',
        Email = 'test@user.com',
        Alias = 'testuser',
        TimeZoneSidKey='America/Los_Angeles',
        LocaleSidKey = 'en_US',
        LanguageLocaleKey = 'en_US',
        EmailEncodingKey = 'UTF-8',
        ProfileId = p.Id
    );
    insert u;

    Resource__c r = new Resource__c(
        Name = 'Test resource'
    );
    insert r;
    
    Case c = new Case(
        Subject = 'Test case'
    );
    insert c;

    Time_Log__c tl = new Time_Log__c(
        Name = 'Test timelog',
        Work_Type__c = 'Development',
        Date__c = System.today(),
        Resource_Name_lookup__c = r.Id,
        Case__c = c.Id
    );
    insert tl;
    
    Test.startTest();
    
    
    
    try {
        TimesheetController.deleteSelectedTimelog(null);
        system.assert(false, 'Should have thrown an exception');
    } catch (AuraHandledException e) {
        system.assert(e.getMessage().contains('error'), 'Exception message was wrong');
    }
    Test.stopTest();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This use case is a great example of how simple dependency injection can make your life. You can add the below lines and inner class.

```
@TestVisible static void setMock(SaveLayer mock) { dml = mock; }
static SaveLayer dml = new SaveLayer();
public virtual class SaveLayer
{
    public virtual void deleteRecord(Id recordId)
    {
        Database.delete(recordId);
    }
}
```

Now in your test, you can just mock out this subservice.

```
class ExceptionMock extends MyController.SaveLayer
{
    public override void deleteRecord(Id recordId)
    {
        throw new DmlException('message');
    }
}
@IsTest static void testMyMethod_Exception()
{
    MyController.setMock(new ExceptionMock());
    
    AuraHandledException thrownException;
    Test.startTest();
        try
        {
        }
        catch (AuraHandledException e)
        {
            thrownException = e;
        }
    Test.stopTest();

    system.assertNotEquals(null, rethrownException, 'The exception should be translated');
}
```

Note also the assertion pattern on the exception. You should *never* assert in your catch block. Your current pattern does not even make any assertion in the case where the controller behavior is incorrect.

Also note that you should not `catch (Exception)` in your controller method. Catch only `DMLException`.

Answer (score 0):

You can coerce the exception by making the Query expression too long

```
TimesheetController.deleteSelectedTimelog('abcde'.repeat(1000));
```

this will cause a

```
System.QueryException: WHERE clause cannot be greater than 4000 characters in length
```

which your code will catch and throw

Comment: Except it should really only be catching `DmlException`.

Answer (score 0):

You could provide incorrect id to `deleteSelectedTimelog` method, e.g. '001000000000000':

```
@isTest 
private static void testDeleteSelectedTimelogError(){
    Test.startTest();
    try {
        TimesheetController.deleteSelectedTimelog('001000000000000');
        Assert.fail('Should have thrown an exception');
    } catch (AuraHandledException e) {
        System.assert(e.getMessage().contains('error'), 'Exception message was wrong');
    }
    Test.stopTest();
}
```

Note: for this to work, you would also need to explicitly select 1 record in your method:

```
@AuraEnabled 
public static void deleteSelectedTimelog(String recordIdToDelete) {
    try {
        Time_Log__c timeLog =[
            SELECT Id
            FROM Time_Log__c
            WHERE Id =: recordIdToDelete
        ];
        delete timeLog;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new AuraHandledException(e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

(missed that originally cause we usually move all selectors to separate selector layer, like `TimeLogData.getById()`)

Comment: curiously, this was my first thought and when I tried this, no exception was thrown

Comment: Sorry, forgot about on more thing. Please check a 'Note' added to the answer.

Answer (score -1):

1. throw new AuraHandledException('To increase test coverage');
2. if(Test.isRunningTest()){ Add the above code line here }

Comment: Should i put this after the test start and before the try catch?

Comment: No inside your Apex Controller try block

Comment: So before my try catch it will check if a test is running, if so then it throws an error?

Comment: Inside your Try Block in your Server Side AuraEnabled Apex Controller, So when your test is running the Test.isRunningTest will return true for all the other cases it will return false and with this it will throw the error by using the throw keyword!

Comment: Okay thanks mate! appreciate the help, didn't know there was an isRunningTest()! :)

Comment: Glad! It helped you Thanks!

Comment: You should ***almost never*** use `Test.isRunningTest()`. You would be better off forgetting it exists.

Comment: @AdrianLarson any specific reason ?